# Hadoop (1.0.1) compile error with libssl

Tags: hadoop

For some reason, I need to compile Hadoop with the follow command:

```
$ ant compile -Dcompile.c++=true -Dlibhdfs=true
```

Then it ended up with following info:

```
[exec] checking for HMAC_Init in -lssl... 
[exec] configure: error: Cannot find libssl.so
[exec] /home/cshou/Documents/Lab/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++/pipes/configure: line 5166: exit: please: numeric argument required
[exec] /home/cshou/Documents/Lab/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++/pipes/configure: line 5166: exit: please: numeric argument required
[exec] no

BUILD FAILED
/home/cshou/Documents/Lab/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml:2102: exec returned: 255
```

Then I checked with (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04)

```
$ apt-cache search libssl
```

Then I got

```
libssl-dev - SSL development libraries, header files and documentation
libssl-doc - SSL development documentation documentation
libssl1.0.0 - SSL shared libraries
libssl1.0.0-dbg - Symbol tables for libssl and libcrypto
dcmtk - OFFIS DICOM toolkit command line utilities
libcherokee-mod-libssl - Cherokee web server - SSL crypto functions plugin
libdcmtk2 - OFFIS DICOM toolkit runtime libraries
libdcmtk2-dev - OFFIS DICOM toolkit development libraries and headers
libssl-ocaml - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL (runtime)
libssl-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL
libssl0.9.8 - SSL shared libraries
libssl0.9.8-dbg - Symbol tables for libssl and libcrypto
libsslcommon2 - enterprise messaging system - common SSL libraries
libsslcommon2-dev - enterprise messaging system - common SSL development files
```

It seems I did install the libssl lib...

I Googled a lot only found a patch for 0.20.0, which should already be fixed in 1.0.1.

Can any one help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

it is a bug,after add a path,it works.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2127